# How Filtering a List from Dropdown List Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, filtering, dropdown

Excuse me i need some help regarding filtering drop down list using VBA i've got a script to created a dropdown list using VBA like this

```
Dim LRow As Long 
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input_PH")

LRow = Worksheets("PH").Range("A" & Worksheets("PH").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = ws.Range("D5")
With Rng.Validation
    .Delete
   .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="='PH'!$A$2:$A$" & LRow
```

now from the drop down list how can i filter it using a value that i input in other colum,

for example E5, i have a list from dropdown list is "exam", "exit", "leave", "gone" and when i enter "ex" in column E5 the Dropdown list in D5 is filtered and become "exam", "exit"

I hope someone can help me for this.
Thanks

Comment: Where do you Set ws? Is it Worksheets("PH") ?

Comment: forgot to add this
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input_PH")

Comment: Right.... so give us an example of the filtering. Where is the filter value coming from? Which range is it filtering? And what will the filtered result look like?

Comment: for example E5, i have a list from dropdown list is "exam", "exit", "leave", "gone" and when i enter "ex" in column E5 the Dropdown list in D5 is filtered and become "exam", "exit"

Comment: E5 of which sheet? And E5 also has a validation list? And how does a single item selection (ex) become a double filter in D5 ( exam and exit) ?
 I think some images might help here. Is ex also a partial match so anything being with ex is put into the filter?

Comment: the Dropdown list in Sheet Input_PH column D5, the list for dropdown list in Sheet PH and the filter value in Sheet Input_PH Column E5

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your sheets?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Tb3rj0Vt1QzEK4zLgLOGaWR4oT8Ig4QT

Comment: the dropdown list in Sheet PH column D5 
there is a macro too make a dropdown list for column D5 using a list that i make in Sheet Input_PH, so how can i filter the dropdown list in column D5 Sheet PH using a value that i input in E5 Sheet PH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it...

- You have a list in an Excel Worksheet("PH").
- The list populates a validation list on cell D5 in Worksheet("Input_PH") configured as a drop-down.
- You want the validation list to be filtered by a value in cell E5 on Worksheet("Input_PH").

### A solution

1. Create a function that returns a filtered list.
2. Use the filtered list for the validation criteria on cell D5 when E5 is updated.

To make life a little easier, name the unfiltered list on Worksheet("PH"). Call it "drop_list" (without the quotes). This avoids the need for LRow in your code snippet above.

### Filter Function

Put this function in your VBA module

```
Function filter_list(the_filter, the_list)
    ' compile a list of filtered values
    Dim filtered_values
    For Each list_item In the_list
        If InStr(LCase(list_item), LCase(the_filter)) > 0 Or the_filter = "" Then
            filtered_values = filtered_values & list_item & ","
        End If
    Next
     ' default value if no match
    filter_list = ""
    ' remove trailing ,
    If Len(filtered_values) > 1 Then filter_list = Left(filtered_values, Len(filtered_values) - 1)
End Function
```

### Validation Update Method

In the VBA editor, put this sub in your worksheet("Input_PH"). It needs to go here to take advantage of the Worksheet_Change event trigger. This is instead of your code snippet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim the_filter As Range, the_list As Range
    Set the_filter = Me.Range("E5")

    If Target.Address = the_filter.Address Then
        Set Rng = Me.Range("D5")
        Set the_list = ThisWorkbook.Names("drop_list").RefersToRange
        filtered_list = filter_list(the_filter.Cells(1).Value, the_list.Value)
        With Rng.Validation
            .Delete
            If filtered_list <> "" Then .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=filtered_list
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

When a value is entered on Worksheet("Input_PH"), Worksheet_Change fires. If the change was in E5, the validation filter on D5 is updated. If E5 is blank,the validation list is populated with the complete list. Invalid values remove the validation.